# PHP File Upload second file does not upload, first file does without error

Tags: php, file, upload, partial

So I have a script I have been using and it generally works well with multiple files...

When I upload a very large file in a multiple file upload, only the first file is uploaded.  I am not seeing an errors as to why.

I figure this is related to a timeout setting but can not figure it out -  Any ideas?

I have foloowing set in my htaccess file

```
php_value post_max_size 1024M
php_value upload_max_filesize 1024M
php_value memory_limit 600M
php_value output_buffering on
php_value max_execution_time 259200
php_value max_input_time 259200
php_value session.cookie_lifetime 0
php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 259200
php_value default_socket_timeout 259200
```

Comment: need html form and the php code you use to handle the uploaded files

Comment: I believe that the session is ending for some reason. Its hosted on Rack space cloud and either the load balancer's are timing out or the tmp directory is filling up...   The problem occurs when I upload multiple large files over 150MB.  Small 20mb files are not an issue.

Comment: Are you sure your host supports setting `php_value`s in .htaccess files? Not all hosts do. You might also try asking in their forum. They may have policies or precedence for this.

Comment: I think a log file needed to judge this kind of issues, It also server related. But I won't bother if... involving windows.